# How do I set a folder destination into a bucket using Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I set the projectId, the bucket name and content type of a file, but I need te upload it to a particular folder into the destination bucket. How do I set the complete url?

This is my preliminary code:

I tried to add a directory inside bucketname or inside filename, but it doesn't work. It seems to be a parameter, but I don't know where do I have to set it.

```
var newObject = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object{
    Bucket = "bucketName",
    Name = "filename", 
    ContentType = "fileContentType"};

var credential = Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromJson(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("credentials.json"));

using (var storageClient = Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.Create(credential)){
     using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)){
         var uploadObjectOptions = new Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UploadObjectOptions();
         await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(newObject,fileStream,uploadObjectOptions,progress: null).ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
}

return Ok();
```

Comment: Can you please give us more details about the operation. Maybe some code that you are already using?

Comment: I already edited the post, including some code and more details of the operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the "folder" in the wrong place. Note that Google Cloud Storage doesn't have real folders or directories, instead it uses [simulated directories](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) which is really just an object with a prefix in its name.

```
bucket = bucket
object = folderName/objectname
```